# C#, access child properties from parent reference?

Tags: c#, inheritance

```
public void GetProps(Parent p){

   // want to access lots of child properties here
   string childProp1 = p.prop1;
   bool childProp2 = p.prop2;
   bool childProp3 = p.prop3;

}
```

However compiler complains that

> "Parent does not contain definition prop1"

The function would take in different subtypes of Class Parent.

All the subclasses have this

```
public override string prop1 { get; set; }
```

Is there a way of accomplishing this?

**EDIT:**
To make the question clearer

I current have a giant if-elseif where i do something like

```
if(p is Child0){
      Child0 ch = p as Child0; 

       // want to access lots of child properties here
       string childProp1 = ch.prop1;
       bool childProp2 = ch.prop2;
       bool childProp3 = ch.prop3;

}else if(p is Child1){
      Child1 ch = p as Child1; 

       // want to access lots of child properties here
       string childProp1 = ch.prop1;
       bool childProp2 = ch.prop2;
       bool childProp3 = ch.prop3;

}else if(...// and many more
```

Now I wanted to remove all the redundant code and make one function that can handle all this.

Comment: I've answered as best I can given the sketchy information - if you could give more context about what you're trying to achieve, that would really help.

Comment: How are you using the keyword ref as a variable parameter?

Comment: @DarrenDavies edited by question

Comment: we need to see the Parent definition, not the child ones; is prop1 declared in the Parent class as public?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: have commented on this in Jon's answer.

Answer (score 7):

If *all* child classes need to have the properties (but with different implementations), you should declare them as *abstract* properties in the base class (`Parent`), then implement them in the child classes.

If some derived classes won't have those properties, then what would you expect your current `GetProps` to do?

EDIT: If you're using C# 4 and you *definitely* can't get a better class design (where the parent class declares the property) you could use dynamic typing:

```
public void GetProps(Parent p) {
    dynamic d = p;
    string childProp1 = d.prop1;
    bool childProp2 = d.prop2;
    bool childProp3 = d.prop3;
    // ...    
}
```

I'd treat this as a last resort though...

Comment: sorry Jon, I'm not a good writer but I added more details to my question. Also I'm accessing this on an external dll and I dont have access to source.

Comment: @KevinBoyd: I doubt that the subclasses have `override` unless the property is actually in the base class... If you could give a short but *complete* example it would really help.

Comment: Jon, the inheritance line is quite long. And I'm using the reference of the toplevel parent, eg Parent ---> SubP10 ----> SubP9 ---> SubP8 ...-----> Child. Any of the parents may have the definiton of prop1.

Comment: @KevinBoyd: So you need to give us a *representative* example - which your current question isn't. If `Parent` doesn't declare `prop1`, what would you expect your code to do if it were given an instance of a type which doesn't have it?

Comment: @KevinBoyd: Not really enough though... does each child declare `prop1` separately? If so, they're really different properties. You *could* potentially use dynamic typing, but frankly it sounds like the class design is somewhat lacking to start with...

Comment: Jon, each child does not define prop1 seperately, one of the classes in the inheritance line defines prop1 and then the other classes override it.

Comment: @Kevin: Then that is the type your method should take, rather than Parent

Answer (score 4):

The solution in case someone need it, it is just to cast the class you receive as a reference as follows:

```
public void GetProps(Parent p){
..
  string childProp1 = ((ChildClass)p).prop1;   
...
}
```

Comment: How do I use this if I don't know what the child class is? I.e, I am looping through a generic colletion and I want to get childs properties.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood from your question, you want to access Children Class members from object of Parent Class.

This behavior is not allowed in OOP.
One way can be as suggested by Jon Skeet to create a Abstract base class and implement the required members in Children Classes.

Other way round can be to assign the required values to members of base class in derived class constructor using base construct. I do not know this will solve your problem or not. But Consider the following snippet for example:

```
 public class BaseClass
{
    public string FirstName = "Base Class";
    public string LastName = "Base Class";
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass()
    {
        base.LastName = "Derived Class";
    }
}

internal class Tester
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseClass objBaseClass = new BaseClass();
        Console.WriteLine("First Name : " + objBaseClass.FirstName);
        Console.WriteLine("Last Name : " + objBaseClass.LastName);

        DerivedClass objDerivedClass = new DerivedClass();
        Console.WriteLine("First Name : " + objDerivedClass.FirstName);
        Console.WriteLine("Last Name : " + objDerivedClass.LastName);

        BaseClass objBaseDerivedClass = new DerivedClass();
        Console.WriteLine("First Name : " + objBaseDerivedClass.FirstName);
        Console.WriteLine("Last Name : " + objBaseDerivedClass.LastName);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

O/P
First Name : Base Class

Last Name : Base Class

First Name : Base Class

Last Name : Derived Class

First Name : Base Class

Last Name : Derived Class

Let me know, if it helps out.

Comment: Pank, thanks for the explanation, but in this case I'm accesing an external library and don't have access to modify the source. Also I want to access child properties from a parent reference. The objects that come in would still be child objects.

Comment: quoting ```This behavior is not allowed in OOP```: are you sure here? isnt grouping common functionality of several classes into the parent class the main benefit of OOP? imagine i got a line ```this.param = "value"``` in each child class. i would thus move this line into parent method, the really basic rule of all OOP and refactoring. but that parent cannot see the child ```param``` but instead assings the ```value``` into its own parent ```param``` (in C#, works well in other languages imho)

Answer (score 0):

If the property is defined in an intermediate class between parent and child and you don't have a reference to that intermediate class at design time then you could use reflection to get the property. But it sounds like you should be using the most relevant sub parent instead of simply parent.

Comment: Nice idea! An example would help though! Reflection and Dynamic as Jon mentiond seem to be existing options.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly (- I'm assuming `Parent` is a base class from which `Child0` `Child1` etc inherit.) – you're just missing a declaration of `prop1` in the parent. It won't get in the way, it will simply be overridden.

Check out this example (which returns "child string") and note that `child` is passed to a method that expects a `ParentClass` instance.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ChildClass child = new ChildClass();
        Text = ParentClass.mymethod(child);
    }
}

class ParentClass
{
    public virtual string s { get { return "parent string"; }  }

    public static string mymethod(ParentClass parent)
    {
        return parent.s;
    }
}

class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public override string s { get { return "child string"; }  }
}
```