# Simple Factory Pattern in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns, factory

I am trying to create a simple factory pattern. Below is my sample code:

IMobile:

```
namespace SimpleFactory
{
public interface IMobile
{
 void Hello();
}
}
```

IPhone:

```
namespace SimpleFactory
{
public class Iphone : IMobile
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, I am Iphone!");
    }
}
}
```

Nokia

```
namespace SimpleFactory
{
public class Nokia : IMobile
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, I am Nokia!");
    }
}
public void NokiaClassOwnMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, I am a Nokia class method. Can you use me 
with Interface");
    }
}
```

MobileFactory:

```
namespace SimpleFactory
{
public class MobileFactory
{
    public IMobile GetMobile(string mobileType)
    {
        switch (mobileType)
        {
            case "Nokia":
                return new Nokia();
            case "iPhone":
                return new Iphone();
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Program:

```
namespace SimpleFactory
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MobileFactory factory = new MobileFactory();
        IMobile mobile = factory.GetMobile("Nokia");
        mobile.Hello(); 
        mobile.NokiaClassOwnMethod();


    }
}
}
```

I would like to access NokiaClassOwnMethod method of the Nokia and Iphone. Can I access NokiaClassOwnMethod method of the Nokia or Iphone class. If not, why? (I can add this NokiaClassOwnMethod method to the Interface and able to access it. But my question is How I can access class own methods? )

Comment: Add `Hello` method to the interface `IMobile`

Comment: @Fabio Yes That I can do it and able to access it. Let's assume if we have some class own methods. How I can use those methods

Comment: What you trying to do generally considered to be bad idea, but indeed "call methods using base class (or interface) refernce" is indeed answered on SO already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370645/c-access-child-properties-from-parent-reference

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov okay. I did not about that it was a bad idea. So you mean I am using a Factory Pattern or DI using interface. I must have all the methods in the interface which I must implement in the child class. So, child class should not contain its own public methods

Comment: @KiddoDeveloper as long as child class follows https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle no one will complain if that child class adds its own public methods to be used in a context where child type is known (i.e. collection of Animals may contain Dog but you should not try to use Dog.Bark via Animal reference, while if you have collection of Dogs you can call Bark on any of them).

Comment: Thank you @AlexeiLevenkov. You are awesome..I got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that you will need to add `Hello` method to your interface:

```
public interface IMobile
{
   void Hello();
}
```

It was not accessible previously because your factory method returned an interface and interface did not contain `Hello()` method. So during the runtime different types can be returned and when you call `Hello` child specific class implementation will be called.
If you want to have access to method/property that doesn't exist in interface but in the concrete implementation, you will need to cast:

```
MobileFactory factory = new MobileFactory();
IMobile mobile = factory.GetMobile("Nokia");
var iPhone = mobile as Iphone;
if(iPhone != null) iPhone.Hello();
```

Comment: yes but I am sending my Nokia object in that IMobile interface. So should not it contains all the methods of the Nokia class?

Comment: @KiddoDeveloper not sure I understand you correctly. Your interface should contain generic to all implementations methods/properties. If Hello if generic for all IMobiles then an interface should have it

Comment: @Olegl Yes you are absolutely correct. Let's assume Hello is not a generic method. It is specific only to Nokia Class. Can I use in that case?

Comment: Then you will need to try to cast interface into specific implementation and call that method

Comment: Okay. So, what I understood is that we can not use child class method from the parent class object. If we have to use it, we must use type casting and this is not a good idea. Right @Olegl

Comment: Yes, you right @KiddoDeveloper. Ideally, a method that takes an abstraction should know nothing about concrete implementations of that abstraction

Comment: @KiddoDeveloper my pleasure