# Including setter property on child class that inherited the property from a read-only interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, properties, readonly

Thought this was a duplicate question but other questions are all slightly different.

I have some parent interfaces and inheriting classes like this:

```
public interface IPerson 
{
  IPersonData PersonData {get;}
  //other stuff
}

public interface IPersonData
{
  public String Name {get;}
  //other stuff
}

public class Person : IPerson
{//need to implement IPersonData
  IPersonData PersonData {get;set;} = new PersonData();
  //other stuff
  PersonData.Name = "JohnDoe";//compiler error somewhere in a method
}

public class PersonData : IPersonData
{//need to implement IPersondata
  public String Name {get;set;}
  //other stuff
}
```

So my goal as you can see is to implement the `IPerson` interface while also being able to write to the Name property of the IPersonData (instantiated as a PersonData). As the code is written here, if I tried to do PersonData.Name = "JohnDoe" the compiler will throw an error because the property is apparently read-only. If I try to change IPersonData to be PersonData pd = New PersonData, then I am obviously no longer implementing the interface requirement.

I have to do this because these are interfaces that are required and are not written or controlled by me. When these interfaces were written originally they were done in a time where they probably didn't have auto-fielded properties.

What I know is that I could implement a field behind it and have the program write to the field when I need to write, and the property can reference the field. However, I feel this is probably not the "correct" way to do things in c# in 2021 where everything is a property and it adds lines of code I feel are probably not needed.

So is there a more "correct" way to do this if I cannot rewrite the interface, or is adding a field the only thing that can be done?

Before someone says "this question has been answered by such and such before" please make sure they are not referring to an INTERFACE inheriting another interface, where that actually does work. Apparently, this issue only exists when a concrete class inherits an interface.

Comment: So you want to be able to do `somePerson.PersonData.Name = "Foo";` Is that right?

Comment: Can you please clarify what *does not* work - the code shown in the post does not look particularly strange... And interfaces make perfect sense to me (it is usually good idea to make interfaces read-only unless there is a strong reason not to, totally unrelated to "the time where they probably didn't have auto-fielded properties.")

Comment: (Maybe you simply asking about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370645/c-access-child-properties-from-parent-reference... - make sure to clarify that is not the case when [edit] the question)

Comment: Not entirely sure what is the question here. Apart from the properties in the `Person` class not being public, the code clearly compiles. Can you explain what is the problem with the code you've posted? You mention a backing field, I assume you know about [Auto-implemented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) ?

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear from the first sentence "So my goal as you can see is to implement the IPerson interface while also being able to write to the Name property of the IPersonData (instantiated as a Person). ".

As sweeper says, when you make any attempt to write to the name as in his example, the code will give an error that says the property is read-only. I'll update the question to be clearer.

Comment: I don't think there is any crossover to Alexei's link, that looks like a completely different issue that has nothing to do with inheritance of interfaces, just regular classes.

Comment: @Plaje The convention in the .NET world when an interface provides _only_ a read-only view of some data then it should be named `IReadOnlySomething` - so for the benefit of everyone concerned you should rename `interface IPerson` to `interface IReadOnlyPerson`. There's no current naming convention for mutable interfaces, however in my projects I use `IMutableSomething` or `IWritableSomething`. I also don't feel you should be having mutable interfaces extending readonly interfaces: it really messes up slot-naming and programmer ergonomics, so your `interface IMutablePerson` should be standalone

Comment: @Plaje Also, ditch the separate interfaces and types for "has-a-Person" - that's just confusing. All you _really_ need is 2 types: `interface IReadOnlyPerson` (for _safe_ read-only views over in-memory-data) and `class Person` for mutability. You really don't need anything else - and if you think you do I think you have a data-modelling problem.

Comment: @Dai unfortunately these interfaces were not designed by me and were made so long ago that they are integrated into too many products to change now. The real interfaces are about production test reporting.

Comment: @Dai also the real interface is very much needed and used, I just simplified it here to make it easier to follow (and to avoid showing off company property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by explicitly implementing the interface. In this example, my implementation makes use of the existing property (adjusted to type `PersonData`):

```
public class Person : IPerson
{//need to implement IPersonData
    public PersonData PersonData { get; set; } = new PersonData();
    IPersonData IPerson.PersonData => PersonData;
    //other stuff
}
```

The code

```
Person fred = new Person(); 
fred.PersonData.Name = "Fred";  
Console.WriteLine(fred.PersonData.Name);
```

outputs

> Fred

The class now fulfills the contract of `IPerson` and provides additional functionality not defined in a contract (interface).

Comment: An `interface` is far from a real "contract" (in the SE sense) though. There's a lot of correctness enforcement issues and business-domain constraints that still cannot be expressed in a C# `interface` but which still make up a contract, for example object-identity and ownership semantics still cannot be easily expressed through interfaces, for example in this case the `Person.PersonData` property is initialized with an object owned by `Person`, but the property is mutable with a public setter, so it's unclear how ownership should work without explicit documentation.

Comment: C# certainly has limitations as to which contract details it handles, though it is still a contract. Yes, ownership is a real issue in many C# applications.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I'll mark it correct though it isn't much different from just adding another line to the definition for a field. In this case though we aren't really adding a field so I guess it's OK. It feels weird to me that we aren't allowed to do this when the compiler should know it was created as a PersonData concrete object and still inherits the interface.

Comment: @EricJ. actually this doesn't compile for me. I still get the same error when trying to write to the Name property. Yours compiles when you do that?

Comment: EDIT: nevermind I was using IPersonData as the object definition still. Works good, thanks.